# Making bold axes titles in base R plots involving vectors having paste()

Tags: r, plot, expression

Suppose I make a plot involving the following lines of code:

```
#Sample Code
calc1 <- 1/4
a <- paste(calc1, "X", sep = "")
calc2 <- (1/2)*100
b <- paste(calc2, "%", sep = "")

x <- c(1, 2, 3)
y <- c(4, 5, 6)

#Plot (Regular Axis Titles)
plot(x, y,
     xlim = c(1, 3),
     xlab = a,
     ylim = c(4, 6),
     ylab = b)
```

Is there a way to make bold axes titles while directly calling vectors having the paste() function? Here is the workaround I made:

```
#Plot (Bold Axis Titles, Workaround)
plot(x, y,
     xlim = c(1, 3),
     xlab = expression(bold("0.25X")),
     ylim = c(4, 6),
     ylab = expression(bold("50%")))
```

Here are the failed attempts:

```
#Attempt 1 
plot(x, y,
     xlim = c(1, 3),
     xlab = expression(bold(a)),
     ylim = c(4, 6),
     ylab = expression(bold(b)))

#Attempt 2
plot(x, y,
     xlim = c(1, 3),
     xlab = expression(bold(paste(calc1, "X", sep = ""))),
     ylim = c(4, 6),
     ylab = expression(bold(paste(calc2, "%", sep = ""))))
```

And here is why I would prefer not to manually encode the returned elements of vectors for axis labelling prior to using expression(bold()):

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set bold axis titles by use of `par(font.lab = 2)`.

```
calc1 <- 1/4
a <- paste(calc1, "X", sep = "")
calc2 <- (1/2)*100
b <- paste(calc2, "%", sep = "")

x <- c(1, 2, 3)
y <- c(4, 5, 6)


par(font.lab = 2)
plot(x, y,
     xlim = c(1, 3),
     xlab = paste(calc1, "X", sep = ""),
     ylim = c(4, 6),
     ylab = paste(calc2, "%", sep = ""))
```